# unable to get the highest price using runMax

Tags: r, quantmod

The runMax does not work . It shows the column High not there

```
library(quantmod)

data <- getSymbols("GOOG",auto.assign=TRUE)

runMax(Hi(data), 30)

Error in Hi(data): subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "High"

Traceback:

1. runMax(Hi(data), 30)

2. try.xts(x, error = as.matrix)

3. is.xts(x)

4. Hi(data)

5. stop("subscript out of bounds: no column name containing \"High\"")
```

the error shows "High" not there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not "runMax" but auto.assign. Here is the suggestion. Using auto.assign=TRUE, the variable chosen is an R-legal name derived from the symbol being loaded (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantmod/versions/0.4.20/topics/getSymbols)

```
library(quantmod)
data <- getSymbols("GOOG",auto.assign=FALSE)
runMax(Hi(data), 30)
```

or

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GOOG",auto.assign=TRUE)
runMax(Hi(GOOG), 30)
```